# where is this wrong in ffmpeg installation and php configuration

Tags: php, video, upload, ffmpeg

hello all i have successfully installed ffmpeg to my computer i can check it by checking ffmpeg-version it returns something logical.

which means the ffmpeg is running successfully on my pac but when i run this code by php i get error  in ffmpeg loading

```
<?php
 extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg'); 
 // Determine the full path for our video
  $vid = realpath('./test/Sample.mp4');

 // Create the ffmpeg instance and then display the information about the video clip.
 $ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie($vid);
 echo "getDuration: " . $ffmpegInstance->getDuration() . "<br />".
  "getFrameCount: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount() . "<br />".
   "getFrameRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameRate() . "<br />".
   "getFilename: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFilename() . "<br />".
    "getComment: " . $ffmpegInstance->getComment() . "<br />".
   "getTitle: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTitle() . "<br />".
   "getAuthor: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAuthor() . "<br />".
        "getCopyright: " . $ffmpegInstance->getCopyright() . "<br />".
     "getArtist: " . $ffmpegInstance->getArtist() . "<br />".
     "getGenre: " . $ffmpegInstance->getGenre() . "<br />".
     "getTrackNumber: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTrackNumber() . "<br />".
    "getYear: " . $ffmpegInstance->getYear() . "<br />".
  "getFrameHeight: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameHeight() . "<br />". 
     "getAudioChannels: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAudioChannels() . "<br />".
   "hasAudio: " . $ffmpegInstance->hasAudio();
      ?>
```

please tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: check extensions in phpinfo()

Comment: how do i check that ?

Comment: echo phpinfo(); But i see that there is a lot of problems like that, people trying to reinstall ffmpeg and its works

Comment: it says mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql

Comment: do i need to install ffmpeg-php now ?

Comment: because i have already installed ffmpeg and using it by my cmd

Comment: if you dont have extension for php, so yes you need to install ffmpeg-php or use ffmpeg using system commands in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like ffmpeg-php module is not installed